# What to use instead of try catch?

Tags: smart-contracts

I have a requirement, there are two contracts Contract A and Contract B.

Contract A calls Contract B , if some error occurs in contract B while calling.
Instead of failing of transaction, Contract B should sends some message to Contract A and then Contract A will receive that message and then  emits a event saying the contract B gets failed.

I know try catch is not possible on tezos, but is there any way I can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an option as a returned value from Contract B:

```
if something is wrong, Contract B returns None to Contract A
if everything is fine, Contract B returns Some value to Contract A
```

You can then use pattern matching in Contract A to adapt the behaviour of the contract to the value returned by Contract B.

Answer from Claude Barde in Slack.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected errors might "never" occur because before trying to send your transaction your wallet will tell you that it will fail

It means :

- you can segregated a bad use case with if..else and tell something back to contract A
- you are unlucky because an event happened in paralell that changed initial conditions, example "gas_exhausted", so it will not pass but you cannot manage this in another way

Answer from Benjamin Fuentes from Slack.